# react shows toast multiple times

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios, react-toastify

Currently i have started learning in React to call API but when component is rendered on browser side from below code toast message is shown two times instead of single time.  Can someone please help me to fix this issue?  Thanks in advance!

```
const [toastShown, setToastShown] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = "All Courses";

    axios.get(`${base_url}/courses`).then(
      (response) => {
        setCourses(response.data);
        if (!toastShown) {
          toast.success("Courses loaded successfully!");
          setToastShown(true);
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        toast.error("Something went wrong!");
      }
    );
  }, [toastShown]);
```

Comment: `toast.success` is enough, remove the `setToastShwon`

Answer (score 0):

In the development mode, `StrictMode` is enabled which runs `useEffect` twice. Try to build the code and test it in `Production` mode. If it runs twice, try to use `AbortController` to stop the first API call, which stops the execution of `then`.

Comment: Remove your toastShown state before testing in production mode.

Answer (score 0):

It's showing twice because you're performing the operation twice.  Note the `useEffect` dependency:

```
}, [toastShown]);
```

So this effect will run if `toastShown` changes.  What does this effect do?:

- Perform an AJAX operation
- Show the Toast
- Set `toastShown` to `true`

So the effect will run once when the component loads with the initial (`false`) value of `toastShown`, and then run again when the component re-renders with the new (`true`) value of `toastShown`.

You appear to have simply over-engineered yourself into this scenario.  Remove `toastShown` entirely:

```
useEffect(() => {
  document.title = "All Courses";

  axios.get(`${base_url}/courses`).then(
    (response) => {
      setCourses(response.data);
      toast.success("Courses loaded successfully!");
    },
    (error) => {
      toast.error("Something went wrong!");
    }
  );
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you update the toastShown state inside the useEffect, it triggers the effect again because toastShown is in the dependency array.You can remove toastShown from the dependency array if you only want the effect to run once when the component mounts.

```
const [toastShown, setToastShown] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  document.title = "All Courses";

  axios.get(`${base_url}/courses`).then(
    (response) => {
      setCourses(response.data);
      if (!toastShown) {
        toast.success("Courses loaded successfully!");
        setToastShown(true);
      }
    },
    (error) => {
      toast.error("Something went wrong!");
    }
  );
}, []);
```